# Getting Data from Smarty Array Within an Array

Tags: arrays, smarty

I have a Smarty array and some of the elements within the array are also arrays.  I'm dealing with someone else's code here and I have to insert some extra bits within the output so I can't just loop through the array and output the results.

The code I'm working with is:

```
{foreach from=$setall item=item}

                    {if $item.req_type != 6}
                        {if $item.attr_value}
                         <div class="detailed_line" >

                            <p>
                               <label>{$item.name}</label>
                                {$item.attr_value|JView:$item.attr_id:$data->id:$item.type:$item.req_type}
                            </p>
                         </div>
                        {/if}
        {/if}
        {/foreach}
```

So, I can get individual values out by using:

```
{$setall.5.attr_value}
```

But if one of the values is another array then I'm not sure how to loop through it and output the values.

This is my first foray into Smarty templates so I'm not even sure where to start.

Any ideas would be gratefully received!

Best regards

Andy Jacobs

---

**Edit: in reply to periklis' answer below:**

Thanks for that.  I tried it with a subtle change to this:

```
{foreach name = "loop" from=$setall.0 item="item" key="key"}
        {if is_array($item)}
        {foreach name = "inner_loop" from=$item item="inner_item" key="inner_key"}
        Inner item:{$inner_item}<br />
        {/foreach}    
        {else}
        Outer item:{$item}<br />
        {/if}
        {/foreach}<br />
```

So, for starters, I'm just trying to output the array in the first position of the main array.  This is what I get:

http://j412.workinprogress.co.uk/component/jomdirectory/23-Friendship-Travel

You can see the data at the top that is the default output.  What I need to do is display some of the values in the setall array, then the description, then the rest of setall.

If you look at Destinations, for example, you'll see that the 4th element for this record should output 'British Isles Europe' but it just says 'array'.

Hope that makes more sense!

Regards

Andy

Comment: Perhaps the value is actually "array" instead of an array? That's what's suggested from the code appearing below the output.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be as the output at the top is correct so the value must be, for example, 'British Isles Europe' for the destinations.

Comment: can you do a var_dump of the array you're trying to print in $setall?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{foreach name = "loop" from=$setall item="item" key="key"}
    {if is_array($item)}
        {foreach name = "inner_loop" from=$item item="inner_item" key="inner_key"}
            Inner item:{$inner_item}
        {/foreach}    
    {else}
            Outer item:{$item}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```